# Action Button showing up but not overflow menu in Android actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am a new developer and trying to show action buttons and overflow menu. 4/6 buttons show in actionBar but i cant see overflow menu with other buttons. Following is the code

res/menu/menu/menu_activity_action.xml

```
<menu  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:title="@string/phone"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        and
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/computer"
        android:title="@string/computer"
        android:icon="@drawable/computer"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:title="@string/gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:title="@string/camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:title="@string/video"
        android:icon="@drawable/video"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:title="@string/email"
        android:icon="@drawable/email"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />
</menu>
```

mainActivity :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_action,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_action, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_action, menu);
    return true;
}
```